# Using tables in constraints in minizinc

Tags: constraints, minizinc

I appreciate if anybody helps me with my question. I need to model the constraint that 4 members of two arrays follow a specific pattern given by the user in minizinc tool.

For example I need X[0],X[1],Y[0],Y[1] to take one of the following patterns:

(0,0,1,1) , (0,1,0,1) and (0,1,1,1).

I appreciate if anybody helps me figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

This is easily achieved using the [table constraint](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/lib-globals.html#extensional-constraints-table-regular-etc):

```
constraint table([X[0], X[1], Y[0], Y[1]], [|
    0,0,1,1 |
    0,1,0,1 |
    0,1,1,1 |
|]);
```